# Can you set HTTP header before posting

Tags: asp.net, http-headers

Pretty sure I know the answer to this one, but want to make sure I'm not missing something...

Running ASP.NET 4.0 and have a request where I need to send a user to a 3rd party app but set an HTTP header value before doing so. This would be a Request header. I can set the Response Header no problem but am unable to do so with Request headers as the collection is read-only. Essentially, the process is as follows:

1. User clicks button to initiate transfer to 3rd party app
2. Page posts back and we grab user info - at this point I need to set the header
3. Issue a Response.Redirect and send them to the 3rd party app.

Note: I'm not stuck on a Response.Redirect; I could change the form to POST to the 3rd party app simply as a means of transferring the user, that's fine.

I believe I could setup an IIS rewrite rule to set the header (based on this article: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/686/setting-http-request-headers-and-iis-server-variables/) but I don't want to go that route as the header value will contain a UserID and I'd rather not expose that to the user at all - even for a brief moment. I certainly understand that even a header isn't invisible as someone could inspect the page, but I'm not concerned with that.

Any ideas would be a great help.

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
using System.Net;

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
req.Headers.Add(new HttpRequestHeader(), "my header content");
```

Comment: Widor - thanks, that would work to set the header but the key is that I'm not simply parsing the response - I need to send the user to that page. This is for a full reporting application so the user will be sent to that app and stay for a bit; not simply request one page and return to our app.

Comment: OK, then you'd need to take the `Request` they generate in step `1.` above and use that for the `req` object. Then you could use `Server.Transfer` to forward the whole lot on to the new location.

Comment: Server.Transfer takes a virtual path and will therefore only work when transferring within the same application - I can't send the user to a 3rd party site.